# GIT plugin for weblogic workshop

Tags: java, git, weblogic

I'm using Weblogic Workshop for my Java project development, as I found it handy since it came along Weblogic Server installation on my machine. Please suggest, if it has an GIT plugin available similar to Eclipse.

Comment: What version are you using? Isn't Workshop based on Eclipse?

Comment: I'm using the version that comes with Weblogic Server 10.3. It's based on Eclipse version 3.3.2, as I can best remember.